# How does a django app start it's virtualenv?

Tags: django, virtualenv

I'm trying to understand how virtual environment gets invoked. The website I have been tasked to manage has a .venv directory. When I ssh into the site to work on it I understand I need to invoke it with source .venv/bin/activate. My question is: how does the web application invoke the virtual environment? How do I know it is using the .venv, not the global python?

More detail: It's a Drupal website with Django kind of glommed onto it. Apache it the main server. I believe the Django is served by gunicorn. The designer left town
_

Comment: It depends, but the app can't start its own environment. Have you talked to whoever set the site up? What's it running on?

Comment: It's most likely in your web server config. Which one are you using?

Comment: I don't see anything in the gconf.py file which is the gunicorn settings (I think). The Apache starts first since it drives the main Drupal site and I don't see any thing in Apache2.conf.
I'm just struck that if the .venv was put there, it must be invoked somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've found how, in my case, the virtualenv was being invoked for the django.

BASE_DIR/run/gunicorn script has:

```
#GUNICORN='/usr/bin/gunicorn'
GUNICORN=".venv/bin/gunicorn"
GUNICORN_CONF="$BASE_DIR/run/gconf.py"
.....
$GUNICORN --config $GUNICORN_CONF --daemon --pid $PIDFILE $MODULE
```

So this takes us into the .venv where the gunicorn script starts with:

```
#!/media/disk/www/aavso_apps/.venv/bin/python
```

Voila

Answer (score 0):

If you use just Django behind a reverse proxy, Django will use whatever is the python environment for the user that started the server was determined in `which python` command. If you're using a management tool like Gunicorn, you can specify which environment to use in those configs. Although Gunicorn itself requires us to activate the virtual environment before invoking Gunicorn 
EDIT: 
Since you're using Gunicorn, take a look at this, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-python-wsgi-apps-using-gunicorn-http-server-behind-nginx

Comment: Thanks for the reference. But reading through it I don't see where the web site invokes the virtualenv. In their case they have Nginx over gunicorn. I'm running Apache over gunicorn. And my Apache conf makes no mention of environments.
Maybe its set earlier, with the boot up of the server?

Comment: Looking again, it's not explicitly mentioned, but you need to activate your virtual environment before you start gunicorn.

Answer (score 0):

Just use absolute path when calling python in virtualenv.
For example your virtualenv is located in `/var/webapps/yoursite/env`
So you must call it `/var/webapps/yoursite/env/bin/python`